# Mesos Spark Slave tried to connect to Master Private IP instead of public IP

Tags: apache-spark, networking, mesos

I've installed a system as followed:

--mesos master private IP of 10.x.x.2 , Public 35.x.x.6

--mesos slave private IP of 192.x.x.10, Public 111.x.x.2

Now the master assigned the task successfully to the slave, however, the task failed. The error message is as followed:

> Exception in thread "main" 17/10/11 22:38:01 ERROR RpcOutboxMessage:
> Ask timeout before connecting successfully
>
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive
> any reply in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by
> spark.rpc.askTimeout

When I look at the environment, the spark.driver.host points to the private IP address of the master 10.x.x.2 instead of it public IP address 35.x.x.6. I look at the Wireshark capture and indeed, there was failed TCP package to the master private IP address.

Now if I set spark.driver.bindAddress from the master to its local IP address, spark.driver.host from the master to its public IP address, I get the following message.

> ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 1 on
> myhostname.singnet.com.sg: Unable to create executor due to
> Cannot assign requested address:

From my understanding, the spark.driver.bindAddress set it for both master and slave, hence the slave get the said error.
Now I'm really wondering how do I proper setup spark to work on this clustering over public IP?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you either have an all private setup or an all public setup. Not in betweens.

Generally you want everything private and if you need any data exposed to the outside you just expose the data endpoint on a public IP.  Example, run all your spark jobs and store the data in S3. Then you enable S3 public access on the bucket.  Using private IPs is generally more secure.

Regarding the `--advertise-ip` parameter on the mesos master. That's for the mesos slaves to find the mesos master. The issue there spark doesn't support a public, private combination so you'll have to do one or the other. You can run your spark workloads on mesos machines that connect to public IPs but that means that you'll have to have an accessible zookeeper, etc for those machines.

Comment: Thanks for answering. As far as my network knowledge goes, I don't see a scenario where I can have an all public setup. Every machine expose to public IP address is assigned with a private address for its internal network. The public IP is not the machine itself but on the router (correct me if I'm wrong). 

Mesos addressed this problem by including the --advertise_IP parameter so the machines can find each other by connecting to this address (which is public). I'm not sure how is it implemented on Spark.

Comment: @TheCyberliem sure. Check my addition to the answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However if you read my problem description carefully you'll see that you can't have an all Public setting without private IP ( As I mentioned, the public IP is never on the machine but on the router. So the machine has it private IP and the router map it to public IP.)